# Overlaying textview with imageview linear layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview, imageview

I've got a few linear layouts stacked on top of each other, the centre one has an imageview. I'm trying to get a textview on top of the imageview in the centre however I'm having trouble. I've tried with relative layout however it messes up all my other layouts. Any simple solutions to this?
EDIT ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageDesc"
        android:src="@null" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDecline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to get the text view on top of the id/picPreview image view

Comment: please post XML (and code?)

Answer (score 5):

LinearLayout is designed to place layouts/views in a row (linearly).

One solution would be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageDesc"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@null" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/picPreviewLbl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Overlay" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was trying to do this for a while, must of missed something out because this works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a TextView in place of the centered ImageView and then set the background of the text be the solid color that you are currently using? Eg.

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Sample Text" ... />
```

Comment: The background isn't always a solid colour, it is set to whatever the camera takes.

Comment: in that case I would recommend @Jim 's answer

Comment: That's what I've got with, thanks for the help anyway.